# jQuery each function is not being executed at dynamically loaded content by $.post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to loop through elements which are returned as dynamically loaded content via the ajax `$.post` method. Here is the code:

```
$.post(ajax_url, {action: 'filter-search-results', term_id: term_id}, function (res) {
    $('.job_listings').empty();
    $('.job_listings').html(res);
    $('.hotel-rate').each(function (i, obj) {
        //...
```

But the `each` function is not being executed.

When I trigger a click event of `body` it works:

```
$.post(ajax_url, {action: 'filter-search-results', term_id: term_id}, function (res) {
    $('.job_listings').empty();
    $('.job_listings').html(res);
    $(document).on('click', 'body', function() {
        $('.hotel-rate').each(function (i, obj) {
            //...
```

It works fine. But I don't want to the `each` to be binded in any event. How can I execute the `each` function without triggering any event?

Comment: Are '.hotel-rate' elements you are trying to loop inside the results of the post? if so, they are in the $(res) object and not in the $ object

Comment: Yes, it is in the result of post. After response from post request HTML content would be changed. Here `res` would generate only `HTML` content.

Comment: I edited my description of the question

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
var items = $('.hotel-rate');
$.each(items, function (index, value) {........
```

just like it is explained in the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looping through the job listings object after it's populated?

```
$.post(ajax_url, {action: 'filter-search-results', term_id: term_id}, function (res) {
    var $jobs = $('.job_listings').html(res);
    $jobs.find('.hotel-rate').each(function (i, obj) {
        //...
```